# how can i delete two chars before - in notepad++

Tags: excel, notepad++

I have database that organize this way

now -  14-17  ,  16-20  ,  1-12  ,  10-1

i want it to be like

after -  17, 20 , 12, 1

thanks!

Comment: Database?  is this a flat text file?  what is this?  I see that you want to keep the 2nd value of each range...

Comment: Why the `Excel` tag?

Comment: it's a flat text

Comment: Please let know what you tried. Also, it is not quite clear what your text looks like exactly. Please format the question correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Notepad++, in the search replace select regular expression and put the following in "Find what":

```
[0-9]*-
```

and put a blank in the "Replace with" as in the picture below:
 [image]

result will be:

```
17 , 20 , 12 , 1
```

That should do the trick.